# Counting polyhedra

Tags: combinatorics, polyhedra

Given $n>6$ points in space are placed in such a way that no three are collinear and no four lie on the same plane. Show number of convex polyhedra with $5$ faces and vertices among the given points is at least $\dbinom{n-4}{3}$. I found a (maybe relevant) thread [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/127423/how-many-vertices-can-a-convex-polytope-have) but this does not work or I can't use it so please help me out. Thanks in advance for all help.

Comment: How do you know it's true, if you don't know how to prove it?

Comment: Well the book says so. Its not technically a book just a collection of problems in which it is asked to prove the statement. Is this really unbelievable? I am sorry for any misunderstanding.

Comment: Sometimes, it helps to know where a problem comes from. There may be similar problems near it that would give a clue. Sometimes, books are wrong. The more information you can give, the more likely someone will be able to help.

Comment: Thank you Gerry anyways it is not technically a book as I said. It is just a collection of problems that I came across. The problem mentioned above is the only one of the type. I don't know if this bound is correct at all that's why I am asking better problem solvers like you. Anyhow many thanks for all the help!!

Comment: There's a corresponding problem one dimension down --- given $n>4$ points in the plane, no three in a line, find a lower bound for the number of convex quadrilaterals determined by the points. There's a paper about it at http://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/uli/Manuscripts/Quadrilaterals.pdf --- maybe some of the ideas in that paper generalize to 3 dimensions.

Comment: I think the problem may be solved in Aichholzer, García, Orden, and Ramos, New results on lower bounds for the number of (≤k)-facets, European J. Combin. 30 (2009), no. 7, 1568–1574, MR2547928 (2010i:52014). I think this paper is freely available on the web.

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at the reference I gave?

Comment: I am sorry Gerry for not replying earlier I hadn't had a chance to see the first article until now and I am still looking for the second article. The first article seems something I can use. Anyways thanks a lot for all the help you sent. Even if I cannot solve the problem I sure have learnt a lot all thanks to you Gerry. Cheers!

Comment: OK. When you get a chance, you could maybe post a summary of what you've learned as an answer to your question, so everyone can share it.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, there are no 5-faced polyhedra among the points.

Since no four points are in the same plane, all of the faces must be triangles. Every edge of a convex polyhedron is in 2 faces, so if we have $e$ edges, then $2 e = 3 \cdot 5$, which is absurd (we cannot have 7.5 edges.)